# Eventbridge rule pattern doesn't match

Tags: aws-event-bridge

I am trying to setup a rule in event bridge where based on incoming message if the pattern is matched, that payload will be send to a queue. The incoming payload will be like following.

```
{
    "sender": "blah_blah",
    "type": "blah",
    "id  ": "123",
    "message": {
      "name": "my name is blah"
  }
}
```

I added it as a Sample event.

[Sample event setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80TqW.png)

Pattern I would like to match is following

```
{
    "type": ["blah"]

}
```

However, when I do a Test pattern, I am getting failure.

[Pattern setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Pvkl.png)

Should this pattern match the incoming event? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After duplicating your setup, I'm assuming you're getting this error:

`The sample event is not valid.`

If you look at the blue box above the Sample event input, you'll see info (and a link) regarding the required fields for the event.

"Using a custom sample event to test event patterns
You can test whether the event pattern matches your custom sample event. When entering your own sample event you must include all of the required fields.
[Learn more about which fields are required.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/APIReference/API_TestEventPattern.html)"